# PIC 16F887 unable to store UART data in buffer

Tags: pic, uart, esp8266

ESP8266 and pic 16f887 both are serial connected with baud rate 9600.problem is when ESP send data to 16f887 then the microcontrolle unable to store receive data in its buffer.

```
#include <xc.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

__CONFIG(FOSC_HS & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_ON & CP_ON & CPD_ON & BOREN_ON & IESO_OFF & FCMEN_ON & LVP_OFF);
__CONFIG(BOR4V_BOR40V & WRT_HALF);

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000L


unsigned char MsgFromPIC[] = "\r\nYou typed :";
unsigned char MessageBuffer[64];

int i=0;
void Delay1Second(void);
unsigned char ReadUSART(void);
void putsUSART(unsigned char c);
void ESPWrite(char* st);

void interrupt INTISR(void)
{
    //check if the interrupt is caused by RX pin
    if(PIR1bits.RCIF == 1)
    {
        if(i<64) //our buffer size
        {
            MessageBuffer[i] = ReadUSART(); //read the byte from rx register
            if(MessageBuffer[i] == '\r') //check for return key
            {
                ESPWrite(MessageBuffer);
                for(;i>0;i--)
                    MessageBuffer[i] = 0x00; //clear the array
                i=0; //for sanity
                return;
            }
            i++;
            PIR1bits.RCIF = 0; // clear rx flag
        }
        else
        {
             ESPWrite(MessageBuffer);
             for(;i>0;i--)
                    MessageBuffer[i] = 0x00; //clear the array
             i=0; //for sanity
             return;
        }
    }

}


void main(void) {

    RCIF = 0; //reset RX pin flag

    RCIE = 1; //Enable RX interrupt

    //****Setting I/O pins for UART****//
    TRISC6 = 0; // TX Pin set as output
    TRISC7 = 1; // RX Pin set as input
    //________I/O pins set __________//

    /**Initialize SPBRG register for required 
    baud rate and set BRGH for fast baud_rate**/
    SPBRG = 129;//129@9600;
    BRGH  = 1; 
    //_________End of baud_rate setting_________//

    //****Enable Asynchronous serial port*******//
    SYNC  = 0;    // Asynchronous  
    SPEN  = 1;    // Enable serial port pins
    //_____Asynchronous serial port enabled_______//
    //**Lets prepare for transmission & reception**//
    TXEN  = 1;    // enable transmission
    CREN  = 1;    // enable reception
    //__UART module up and ready for transmission and reception__//

    //**Select 8-bit mode**//  
    TX9   = 0;    // 8-bit reception selected
    RX9   = 0;    // 8-bit reception mode selected
    //__8-bit mode selected__//

    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;    // peripheral intrrupt enable
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;     // GLOBL interrupt enable

   // putsUSART('k');

    while(1) //infinite loop
    {

    }

    return;
}

unsigned char ReadUSART(){
    while(!RCIF );

    if(OERR){
        CREN = 0;
        CREN = 1;
    }

    return RCREG;
}
void putsUSART(unsigned char c){
    while(!TXIF);
    TXREG= c;
    //while(!U1STAbits.TRMT);
}
void ESPWrite(char* st){
    char k=0;
    for(; k<i; k++){
        putsUSART(st[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is RTS/CTS implemented on the ESP8266 and if so, have you set it up on the PIC?

Comment: sorry there is no RTS/CTS...only RX/TX pin are available...

Comment: *"Not working"* is not a useful description.  You need to explain what *is* happening, in contrast to what you expected to happen.  For example, are bytes being sent, but with unexpected content?  Is the baud rate wrong?  Are no bytes being sent when expected, etc?

Comment: Not available where? On the PIC or the ESP8266? If they are on the ESP8266 and you do not implement it on the PIC you will, likely, have problems.

Comment: @debottam you kind of need a question for people to answer, a specific one.

Comment: thanx for your cooperation....when i am connect pic with my pc using serial cable and send data to pic after received complete data PIC send back same data to pc. now if i connect ESP and PIC together and sending data to ESP through mobile , then PIC unable to send back that string. Now my question is when i connect PIC with my PC its working i.e PIC received a string and store its buffer after that PIC send back same string to PC. In the case of ESP, PIC not work as like work with PC.

Comment: You said "only first time its work, after that its not working....." does that mean the PIC correctly receives and sends back the _first_ string from the mobile?

Comment: Yes....but only first time...I don't why it not send every time after received data...is there anything to be change in this code....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it stops sending data to the ESP8266, but I can see two errors in your code:-

```
if(OERR){
    OERR = 0;
    OERR = 1;
}
```

`OERR` (receive overrun error flag) is read-only. If for some reason the UART receive buffer overruns it will stop receiving characters. To clear the overrun error you should clear and set `CREN` (Continuous Receive Enable).

```
PIR1bits.RCIF = 0; // clear rx flag
```

`RCIF` is read-only. It is automatically cleared when all characters in the UART receive buffer have been read.

Comment: thanx for helping...its corrected in my code....i.e          
     if(OERR) // check for Error 
    {
        CREN = 0; //If error -> Reset 
        CREN = 1; //If error -> Reset 
    }  ....the problem is when i connected ESP with mobile and sending data  from mobile to ESP, then pic can not store the received data in its buffer. ....